# What is the error in the following working?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$$\frac{\int_0^1 (1-x^{50})^{100}\mathrm{d}x}{\int_0^1(1-x^{50})^{101}\mathrm{d}x}$$

The question asks us to evaluate 5050 times the above fraction>
To solve this i had made the following substitution:-

$$(1-x^{50}) \longrightarrow t$$
So,
$$-50(x^{49})d{x} =d{t}$$

I multiplied numerator and denominator of the question with $-50(x^{49})$
and the fraction reduced to :- 
$\frac{\int_1^0[t^{100}]\mathrm{d}t}{\int_1^0[t^{101}]\mathrm{d}t}$

But this gives me a wrong answer, the answer is supposed to be 5051,could someone point out he error in my working or give a better way to arrive at the answer please?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot multiply on top and bottom by $-50x^{49}$, it is inside the integral, not outside!

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\int(1-x^n)^m dx=(1-x^n)^m\int\ dx-\int\left(\dfrac{d (1-x^n)^m}{dx}\int 
dx\right)dx$$

$$=x(1-x^n)^m-m\int(1-x^n)^{m-1}(-nx^{n-1})x\ dx$$

$$I_m=x(1-x^n)^m-mn\int(1-x^n)^{m-1}\{(1-x^2)-1\}\ dx$$

$$\implies I_m=x(1-x^n)^m-mn\left(I_m-I_{m-1}\right)$$

$$\iff(1+mn)I_m=x(1-x^n)^m+mnI_{m-1}$$

$$\implies(1+mn)\int_0^1(1-x^n)^m\ dx=mn\int_0^1(1-x^n)^{m-1}\ dx$$